# Where do I get xcb_event.h?

Tags: make, xcb, sxhkd

I'm 'make'-ing SXHKD on MX Linux to try keybindings and I get:

```
$ make
cc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DVERSION=\"0.6.1\"  -c -o sxhkd.o src/sxhkd.c
src/sxhkd.c:25:10: fatal error: xcb/xcb_event.h: No such file or directory
 #include <xcb/xcb_event.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [<builtin>: sxhkd.o] Error 1
```

Please help me understand, so if I'm not mistaken it's compiling sxhkd.c in the src folder, is the include header saying to go into an xcb folder and find xcb_event.h but the xcb folder is missing?

I've looked everywhere on the net and I can't find xcb_event.h

Honestly I'm not confident or experienced yet please lend me some direction.

Thanks

Comment: Since MX appears to be Debian-based, it should be provided by package `libxcb-util-dev` I think

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt install libxcb-util0-dev
sudo apt install libxcb-keysyms1-dev
```

will solve your issue.

In the future you might want to use:

```
apt-file search /usr/include/xcb/xcb_event.h
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply Artem. I think libxcb-util0-dev was successful, however now I'm getting 'xcb/xcb_keysyms.h: No such file or directory'. Also, for some reason I get: bash: apt-file: command not found. Sorry, I hope I'm going to be opening a can of worms. Thanks again

Comment: @1toneboy I've updated the answer to also provide you with the apt-file utility.

Comment: Thanks again Artem, I got it working due to your assistance. I like to download the .deb files so I have them for offline installation at a later date, but for some reason I had to actually do: sudo apt install libxcb-keysyms1-dev, because going to the repository didn't work for some reason I don't understand. Cheers!